# python matplotlib issue making it to go from left to right

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

I have an issue with matplotlib chart, I've been trying multiple ways, but can't seem to make it work, I want a chart that goes from left to right, I have data that looks like this:
prices = [0.03, 0.025, 0.01, 0.01, 0.05, 0.02]
time = ['00:00', '00:05', '00:10', '00:15', '00:20', '00:00']
I want the chart to go from left to right, but when it goes to the last position '00:00' it goes back to the left side. Is there a chance to make it create new tick '00:00' after '00:20'? Below is the code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as plticker


stored_prices = [0.03, 0.025, 0.01, 0.01, 0.05, 0.02]
prices_time = ['00:00', '00:05', '00:10', '00:15', '00:20', '00:00']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.title("X")
plt.tick_params(axis='y', which='both', labelleft=False, labelright=True)

plt.plot(prices_time, stored_prices)
plt.grid()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.03, right=0.86)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
loc = plticker.MultipleLocator(base=2) # this locator puts ticks at regular intervals
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
print(stored_prices, prices_time)
plt.show() #Preview of chart
```

Here is image to explain what I mean, after '00:20' it isn't creating '00:00' to the right of '00:20' but goes back to '00:00' that is already created on the left of the graph :
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "go left to right"? Can you share an example?

Comment: Added the image to the main thread

Comment: I expect that this is due to the fact that there are two elements of equal value in in your `prices_time` list. If you change the second `00:00` to something different, does the graph look as you'd hope?

Comment: Yes, if I would change it to something else it will be ok, however the issue is that I would like 00:00 on the right side of 00:20 and I am looking for a way to make it work, if it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your x-values are equidistant (except for the last one), you can just use any sequence of equidistant numbers to plot them. It may be an arbitrary decision whether to show the last point at the same distance.

Then you just have to manually set the x-ticks and label them with the real values:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as plticker


stored_prices = [0.03, 0.025, 0.01, 0.01, 0.05, 0.02]
prices_time = ['00:00', '00:05', '00:10', '00:15', '00:20', '00:00']
x = range(len(prices_time))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.title("X")
plt.tick_params(axis='y', which='both', labelleft=False, labelright=True)

plt.plot(x, stored_prices)
plt.grid()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.03, right=0.86)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
# loc = plticker.MultipleLocator(base=2) 
# this locator puts ticks at regular intervals
# ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(prices_time)

print(stored_prices, prices_time)
plt.show() #Preview of chart
```

[image: repeated x plot]